# Possible to grab and store available wireless networks?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

Is it possible to grab and store the available wireless networks that my Windows 10 laptop sees?

I don't mean just the ones I log onto but all those that pop up as options when selecting a wireless network to join.

Surely it is stored somewhere (even in a temp file) before it is displayed in the GUI that one sees when clicking on the wireless network symbol in the tray.

Comment: "Grab": List? Use a tool like Nirstoft's WiFi Info view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can list and store wireless networks with this command:

```
netsh wlan  show networks  mode=bssid > networks.txt
```

This will store the list of visible networks, along with information about them in a file called `networks.txt`.

Comment: network should be networks